# How do I bypass authentication in an ASP.NET project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-webpages

Facts:

1. I have inherited an ASP.NET C# project.
2. The project contains the following files: (a) default.aspx (b) index.aspx (c) global.asax (d) Web.config
3. The project runs on a server that requires authentication.
4. I am trying to do some dev work on my computer without requiring authentication.
5. I can't find the right part of the code to comment out or otherwise modify to bypass authentication.

What can I post that would help someone help me?

Update: I found the code

```
  <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server"> <%-- OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">--%>
```

in index.aspx. There are no other references to "Login1_Authenticate" in the project.

It's been so long since I worked on this code that I forgot just about everything about how ASP.NET works.

Comment: From memory, forms authentication on a web form project is usually done in the web.config. But that’s different from server requiring authentication, I believe that’s usually a setting on iis for that web app. However that shouldn’t be a problem for local development.

Comment: The auth might be done with [Attributes] on methods. Normally I'd start unpicking something like that from the login page; run it normally in a browser, inspect some element on the page like the password field, and get its ID, classname or something like a localization string it uses, search the whole project for it, find the receiver of the form submission that does the login, see what it sets up upon successful login - perhaps a security principal/cookie that is then handled by attributes, so everything else is secured by some [Authorize] attribute on the controller method

Comment: I updated the post to indicate that I found an "OnAuthenticate" clause.